# MassTransit Ensure Queues Created before Publishing Messages

Tags: publish-subscribe, masstransit

We have multiple services and use the publish/subscribe pattern for sending events from service A to be handled by other services (B & C). The goal is to allow multiple queues to receive messages from a Producer by matching the binding key / topic.

This works fine if services B & C start first.  In that case, the Subscribe method creates the Exchanges and Queues to receive the messages when published.  However, if service A starts first, then the published messages are lost as the receiving queues are not created.

Looking for the Best Practice way to ensure the queues are created before publish.  The producer does not have knowledge of the consumers, and there may be more consumers over time for a given message type, so we can't have the producer code take responsibility for queue creation.

Our current implementation is using RabbitMQ on the backplane, but we want to migrate over time to SQS and Azure Service Bus, so we need this to be Message Broker agnostic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer, start your consumer services before you start your publishers.

Alternatively, you could use the `DeployTopologyOnly` flag with a custom build or command-line to deploy the queue/exchanges/bindings without actually starting the consumers, but it will still be the consumer service with all of its configuration.

Comment: Thank you, since our system is distributed we can't ensure that subscribers go up first 100% of the time even though I totally agree with your approach. 

We'll look into your suggestion (starting here https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/deploy.html)

We'll probably create a console app that runs during deployment and goes over all IConsumer implementations in our assemblies, adds them to the IRegistrationConfigurator, using DeployTopologyOnly = true and running DeployAsync.